# How to create simple custom field in django?

Tags: python, django, django-custom-field

I want to create two additional properties of `TextField` such as property1 and property2 so that I can access them in template like

```
{% for field in form %}
  {{ field.property1 }}
  {{ field.property2 }}
{% endfor %}
```

my current model looks like

```
class ResponseModel(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ans1 = models.TextField()
    ans2 = models.TextField()
    submit_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.author) + str(self.submit_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to access the model properties in the template you should pass them through the view.py:

```
**views.py**

from .models import *

def index(request):
   context={
      'form': ResponseModel
   }

   return render(request, 'path/to/template', context)
```

And in index.html (Template):

```
{% for field in form %}
   {{ field.property1 }}
   {{ field.property2 }}
{% endfor %}
```

That should work just fine, let me know if you got it.

Comment: I couldn't make myself clear I'm sorry. I want to create two additional properties of TextField so that I can access them. I shall edit my question.